# How is code executing after an exception?

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-debugging

I must be missing something... How can an exception be thrown, yet the code following the exception still gets hit in the debugger?

```
private UpdaterManifest GetUpdaterManifest()
{
    string filePathAndName = Path.Combine(this._sourceBinaryPath, this._appName + ".UpdaterManifest");

    if (!File.Exists(filePathAndName))
    {
        // This line of code gets executed:
        throw new FileNotFoundException("The updater manifest file was not found. This file is necessary for the program to run.", filePathAndName);
    }

    UpdaterManifest updaterManifest;

    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePathAndName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        // ... so how is it that the debugger stops here and the call stack shows
        // this line of code as the current line? How can we throw an exception
        // above and still get here?
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UpdaterManifest));
        updaterManifest = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(fileStream) as UpdaterManifest;
    }

    return updaterManifest;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you catch the exception farther up the chain?

Comment: Maybe you are looking at different threads?

Comment: Is this code accessed from multiple threads?

Comment: I would try first to: clean, and rebuild the solution. also add a break-point at the enter point of your function (it may be called twice).

Comment: Are you sure that the assembly you're debugging is matching the version you're seeing in Visual Studio? Perhaps the Debugger just has "old" line numbers (you perhaps deleted some lines) and thus shows the wrong line?

Comment: @AndreasCarlbom This is what im thinking too

Comment: To confirm - is the exception message the "The updater manifest file was not found..." one? If so, it is *probably* just the IDE being off by a line...

Comment: Are you sure your exception is getting thrown there, or is there somewhere else in your code, further down the chain that could be throwing a FileNotFoundException?

Comment: @AndreasCarlbom how would that make it hit the line mentioned?

Comment: First, even if there were multiple threads (and there are, ha), how would *any* thread get past that line of code if the file didn't exist? And, Marc: yes, the exception is the one with my custom message. I did a rebuild and I'm still having the same issue. Still investigating...

Comment: @Erix: It would make it not break execution when the exception is thrown ..

Comment: @AndreasCarlbom execution would switch to the catching code, so the line would still not be hit.

Comment: @BobHorn Probably not the case here, *but*: Filesystems are not reliable in terms of "it was (not) here  10 nanoseconds ago, so it will (not) be here now". Meaning the statement could evaluate to FALSE for one thread and to TRUE for the thread following right behind. Erik Lippert has a fantastic blog post on that: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx

Comment: Excellent point. I don't think that's the case here, because that file indeed never existed during my testing. But still a good point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some scenario's where this can generally happen:

- when the option "Require source files to exactly match the original version" switched off. In that case, you don't get a warning when your files are out of sync.
- when the IDE asks for *"There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?"*, in which case the IDE can be wrong about the correct line, because it runs an earlier version.
- when you are debugging a release version of your code, where certain parts are optimized away. This results in the highlighted line to be the next available line in the source that reflects and actual statement in the optimized code (this you'll often see when debugging with external assemblies that are optimized).

---

EDIT: I kind-of misread your code. Between the "throw" and the line that gets highlighted, there's only a declaration of a variable, no code at all to be executed. I assume that you meant that the code "using..." was highlighted? Because that's as expected: it is the first line after the throw-statement (the throw-statement itself doesn't "catch" the error for the debugger).

See screenshot: 
[image]

Comment: "Require source files..." is checked. Also, there are no build errors. I'm not debugging the Release version. This is going to end up being something silly, where I should have known, but right now I'm stuck.

Comment: Thanks, Abel. I was expecting the catch block to be the next line shown when hitting F10 on the throw statement. Like Marc said, maybe it's just the IDE being off a line. My exception looks exactly as you have shown above. Once I hit F10 after that point, I'm correctly taken to the catch block.

Comment: @BobHorn: you should see it like this: the debugger will break on every throw, and it will halt on the statement right after the throw (often that's the line where it unwinds to). You can fix this by checking "Break only on user-unhandled exceptions" (or remove the checkbox for this specific exception) and adding a manual breakpoint in your catch-clause.